# Android Gradle add native library

Tags: android, gradle

I would like to include a native library in an Android project in gradle. This comes from: Libjitsi https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-android.

The file I need to include is libjnopensles.so.

Answer (score 1):

create a directory named "jniLibs" in "main" directory and put the file in the right abi directory (arm64-v8a / armeabi-v7a / x86 / x86_64), example:

```
main/jniLibs/arm64-v8a/libjnopensles.so
```

Comment: In the Libjitsi project  the path is jitsi-android/lib/native/armeabi/ i have see in https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis#sa this is Deprecated...